# Not able to get data from local DB in diff Web Role

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, database-connection, azure-web-roles

I've created very simple MVC5 project with two Web roles . webRole1 with local DB which was created by code first (and generate the view by scaffold) this is working fine ,I was able to run it get view data and create data in the local DB.

Now I created very simple API in the WebRole1 to read the data from the DB which is working and I get the data via the API

I created WebRole2 and The problem is that I dont able to read the data in from this API (which is in web role1 ) in webRole2,How should I do that?I getting null for the key that I provided which is exist in DB

I can share the project in one drive if its OK.

**This is the model of WebRole1**

```
namespace WebRole1.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConfigModelDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ConfigModelDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\User.mdf;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**This is the simple API which read the data from the local DB (the data found if I call this API from webRole1**

```
namespace WebRole1.Models
{
    public class UserApi
    {
        private ConfigModelDbContext db = new ConfigModelDbContext();

        public User getDbData()
        {
            User user = db.User.Find("user1");
            return user;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1983303.aspx?Cannot%20Get%20data%20from%20local%20DB) by Russriguez:

> Configure the second WebRole to point at the .mdf in the first WebRole (MVC project), e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Path\To\The\Database\Person.mdf;Initial Catalog=Persons;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> replace "C:\Path\To\The\Database\Person.mdf" with the actual full path
>   to the database file that is in WebRole1's App_Data directory.

Only problem is that this is an absolute path, so all developers need their repository in the same place.  Not ideal, but I couldn't get relative paths to work.  I tried:

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\[project-with-db]\App_Data\[db-name].mdf
```

assuming that the base directory of the second web role would be:

```
[src-root]\[azure-project]\csx\Debug\roles\[web-role-project-2]\approot
```